# Mule: From Large CSV Get Header Only

Tags: mule, dataweave

I am facing issue while pulling header value CSV with a "," comma value separation.
Input:

```
sku,Description,data
1223,"Test Description,hello",
456,"Test",
```

Output

```
sku,Description,data
```

I tried with,(Converting to String)

```
keys = payload.split('\n')[0]
```

but due to large size it hitting the performance. Is there a way to get first line of csv without splitting with expression component or dataweave . Initially i got org.mule.transport.file.ReceiverFileInputStream object which i converted to string.

Answer (score 3):

Try this..

```
%dw 2.0
output application/java
---
payload[0] pluck $$ joinBy ","
```

This should do the trick for you.

Comment: Please select this as the answer if this has achieved what you wanted, so that it can be of help to others who are trying to solve a similar problem. Thanks